# Firebase, gps location and speed

Tags: android, firebase

i want to build a traffic report app that gets gps location and speed from a user that is driving and calculates and sends the traffic conditions of the closest streets.
Can i use Firebase to store the data and sync the result to every device?
Should i have a server app that calculates the conditions or not?

Comment: have you tried anything.If yes then plz show.

Comment: i found this that will help https://www.dropbox.com/s/6cbkdl8nywzrn14/20%20Recipes%20for%20Programming%20PhoneGap.pdf?dl=0. if you give me your email i can share the code when i'm done